# Taskfactory Filter Rows Transform Expression

Tags: sql, ssis

I am trying to write an expression to filter out a specific data set via an SSIS package with task factory "Filter Rows Transform 4.1.0.115".

The Month expression i am using is:

```
MONTH(GETDATE())
```

this expression works great, however; i want to filter by a field with the above expression.
Some like:

```
MONTH(GETDATE(), [TS Stage Open])
```

Can someone assist me with the correct expression to filter this month and field. The expression should only filter and return this months data with the month.

I am not sure how to write the correct expression for this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Arron

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I don't have PragmaticWorks' TaskFactory installed, looking at the [documentation](https://help.sentryone.com/taskfactory/Index.html?TaskFactory1.html) `MONTH(GETDATE(), [TS Stage Open])` looks clearly wrong. What should it do? Return the month number for the current date and/or `[TS Stage Open]`.

If you want to ensure that the value of  [TS Stage Open] and the current month are the same, then based on the sample, it'd be something like `In(MONTH([TS Stage Open]), MONTH(GETDATE())`.

```
MONTH([TS Stage Open]) == MONTH(GETDATE()
```

Should work with the base SSIS Dataflow controls as well as TF's. That expression compares the month of our column [TS Stage Open] to the current month and yields a boolean (true/false) value for the operation.

In the comments, you've indicated

> I am trying to return current month all records for April 2015

and clearly the above is only handling the Month aspect. To factor in Year, you need to indicate it as such

```
MONTH([TS Stage Open]) == MONTH(GETDATE() && YEAR([TS Stage Open]) == YEAR(GETDATE()
```

- `==` do these things match
- `&&` Is first AND second thing true

Something to be careful about though, filters are best applied to the source system. There's no need to pull back data for the life of the system if you only need current month. Modify your source query to apply the filter at the database level.

```
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.MySource AS D 
WHERE 
    D.[TS Stage Open] >= CAST(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS date)
    AND D.[TS Stage Open] < DATEADD(month, 1, CAST(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS date));
```

Note that I do not use `BETWEEN` as it can have unexpected consequences if you aren't paying attention (and your columns have a time component). I also do not apply functions to my columns so we can get nice SARGable queries.

- [What do BETWEEN and the devil have in common?](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common)

Comment: Thanks billinkc. So the i am trying to return current month all records for April 2015. I ran both of the expression and it returned all records in April for all years. Looking for this month of this year.

Comment: thank you for the explanation & links, that help me understand tremendously. Also the expression worked great.